# Closing of sessionFactory saves the data to HSQL

Tags: java, hibernate, hsqldb

I am using HSQL as db and written the application using Hibernate. Find the following application.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <!-- Database Connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:file:employeeDb;shutdown=true;hsqldb.write_delay=false;</property>
        <property name="connection.username">sa</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>

        <!-- Enable the logging of all the generated SQL statements to the console -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Format the generated SQL statement to make it more readable, -->
        <property name="format_sql">false</property>

        <!-- Hibernate will put comments inside all generated SQL statements to 
            hint what’s the generated SQL trying to do -->
        <property name="use_sql_comments">false</property>

        <!-- This property makes Hibernate generate the appropriate SQL for the 
            chosen database. -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property>

        <!-- mappings for annotated classes -->
        <mapping class="com.sample.Employee" />

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Employee.java**

```
package com.sample;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String designation;
    private int age;
    private double salary;

    public Employee(){

    }

    public Employee(int id, String firstName, String lastName, String designation, int age, double salary) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.designation = designation;
        this.age = age;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getDesignation() {
        return designation;
    }

    public void setDesignation(String designation) {
        this.designation = designation;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(double salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

}
```

**TestEmployee.java**

```
package com.sample;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class TestEmployee {

    /* Step 1: Create session factory */
    private static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Employee emp1 = new Employee(1, "Hari Krishna", "Gurram", "Senior Software Developer", 26, 80000);
        Employee emp2 = new Employee(2, "Shreyas", "Desai", "Team Manager", 35, 150000);
        Employee emp3 = new Employee(3, "Piyush", "Rai", "Senior Software Developer", 26, 100000);
        Employee emp4 = new Employee(4, "Maruti", "Borker", "Software Developer", 26, 60000);

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = getSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(emp1);
        session.save(emp2);
        session.save(emp3);
        session.save(emp4);
        session.flush();
        session.getTransaction().commit();

        session.close();
        //sessionFactory.close();

    }
}
```

When I un comment the line 'sessionFactory.close()' in the file 'TestEmployee.java' application saves the data perfectly. But when I comment the line 'sessionFactory.close()', my data is not getting saved. Why do I need to close the sessionFactory? Is there any way that I can persist the data without closing sessionFactory?

Find the stack trace

```
INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@a22cb6a] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
Hibernate: create table Employee (id integer not null, age integer not null, designation varchar(255), firstName varchar(255), lastName varchar(255), salary double not null, primary key (id))
Nov 09, 2016 6:22:08 PM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl handleException
WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:524)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:470)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.createTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:273)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:309)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:445)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:710)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
    at com.sample.TestEmployee.<clinit>(TestEmployee.java:8)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Table already exists: EMPLOYEE in statement [create table Employee]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
    ... 13 more

Hibernate: insert into Employee (age, designation, firstName, lastName, salary, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Employee (age, designation, firstName, lastName, salary, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Employee (age, designation, firstName, lastName, salary, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Employee (age, designation, firstName, lastName, salary, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Nov 09, 2016 6:22:08 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl stop
INFO: HHH10001008: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:hsqldb:file:employeeDb;shutdown=true;hsqldb.write_delay=false;]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your comments clarified the situation, this is normal behaviour for HSQLDB. It will store all shanged from workfiles to persistent log file (due to shutdown=true).In order for it to work, you need to shutdown the factory before application terminates. To automate this process simply use shutdown hook [Runtime.addShutdownHook(Thread)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread)) like this

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(){
    public void run(){

       //CLOSE SESSION FACTORY HERE
     }
});
```

So basicly, your changes were persisted in your case, but you could not see them from the outside of the application as they were not restored when you boot up HSQLDB again in different process (eg from build in db viewer or Eclipse IDE db tools)

Comment: Yes changes are stored to employeeDb.log file, but they are getting stored to employeeDb.script file on closing the sessionFactory. Thanks for the clarifying

Comment: That is exactly how HSQLDB works. I have bumed into this some time in the past and was struggle with this couple of minutes, as this was not so obvious :)

Comment: I updated the property hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto to update, When I ran second time with different data,<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>, still it is trying to create the table and failed. Any idea on this

Comment: Added the stack trace

Comment: Try change the key of property to `hbm2ddl.auto`

Comment: Same Error. I am using Hibernate 5.2.4.Final

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to `close()` your factory but you have to `flush()` the changes. Flush is done automaticly when closing.

Remove `session.flush()` as it is flushed upon commit.

Typical template for DB operations that works in any case (unless you break something in the configuration) is as follows:

A typical transaction should use the following idiom:

```
 Session sess = factory.openSession();
 Transaction tx;
 try {
     tx = sess.beginTransaction();
     //do some work
     ...
     tx.commit();
 }
 catch (Exception e) {
     if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
     throw e;
 }
 finally {
     sess.close();
 }
```

Iv done this that way many times in my experience and it always worked. This is statet by Hibernate's docs as well. No additional flushesh etc. needed. Try it out.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I removed the flush statement. But my problem is data is not getting persisted. It is stored on closing sessionFactory

Comment: It worked for databases like RDBMS. But HSQLDB is in-memory database, I am not sure, whether am I missing some configuration or not.

Comment: <property name="connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:file:employeeDb;shutdown=true;hsqldb.write_delay=false;</property>

Comment: Ahhh that is different. Yes i had the same problem to reflect the changes as well. HSQDB will store changes (operation log) to the pesistent log file upon shutdown (shutdown=true) so when the connection is closed, and that happens when you close session factory :) 
To fix it, add a Runtime#addShutdownHook where you will be closing SessionFactory upon JVM termination :)